# Setting Last Modified HTTP Header on static Home Page

Tags: headers, cache, http

In response to the [question asked here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257085/help-pinpointing-source-of-caching-issue) I find myself and this other user needing a solution to set a last modified header that contains the date and time of the most reicent post. Since we both in many themes have the home page set to a static page and then coding our dynamic content into the static files we are missing that important header to make sure cached homepages update when there are new posts.

So, how can we set a last modified HTTP header on a page that it set to the most recent Post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Last-Modified header for visitors on the front-page

It's useful to see how the *Last-Modified* header is added to the feeds, in the [`wp::send_header()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/55df308b4d4ea733a3738d8c210ffb0ab0d7d7bf/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L399) method.

If we want to be able to use `is_front_page()`, then the filters `wp_headers` or `send_header` are probably applied to early.

We could instead use the `template_redirect` hook to target the front-page, before the headers are sent and after `is_front_page()` is ready.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Set the Last-Modified header for visitors on the front-page 
 * based on when a post was last modified.
 */

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( &$wp )
{
    // Only visitors (not logged in)
    if( is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    // Target front-page
    if( ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    // Don't add it if there's e.g. 404 error (similar as the error check for feeds)
    if( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['error'] ) )
        return;

    // Don't override the last-modified header if it's already set
    $headers = headers_list();
    if( ! empty( $headers['last-modified'] ) )  
        return;

    // Get last modified post
    $last_modified = mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', get_lastpostmodified( 'GMT' ), false );

    // Add last modified header
    if( $last_modified && ! headers_sent() )
        header( "Last-Modified: " . $last_modified . ' GMT' );

}, 1 );
```

Here we used the core PHP functions [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), [`headers_list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) and [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) and the WordPress core function [`get_lastpostmodified()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_lastpostmodified/)

The *Etag* header could be added here too as the *md5* of the last modified date.

We can then test it from the command line with e.g.:

```
# curl --head https://example.tld
```

or just use the shorthand parameter `-I` to only fetch the HTTP headers.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, I am thinking it might be better to check the set header against the discovered last modified date just to be sure it is correct. `if( $headers['last-modified'] <= $Last-Modified )`. Remove the !empty statement and wrap the add header in this?

Comment: yes that might be a good suggestion, if you want to override that header, added by another plugin. Just check if it's set before using it. Feel free to edit the answer. PS missing curly brackets for single IF lines is valid PHP . @JpaytonWPD

Comment: It provides better consistency and reduces potential errors in the future. Especially on a site like this where inexperienced users are likely to add lines and then ask a question because it stopped working. There is no negative effect with their presence.  But you are correct, it is totally valid.

Comment: Can you explain this part to me? Or send me a reference to it? `function() use ( &$wp )` How does this differ from building a function and adding it by name with the add_action?

Comment: Sure: We can't change what input arguments are defined in the `do_action` parts. The `use` keyword makes it possible, with anonymous functions, to bring in the variable(s)  from the parent scope (by reference `&` here). See e.g. [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160). @JpaytonWPD

Comment: ... the `$wp` is a global, so an alternative would be `$GLOBALS['wp']` but I made a [promise here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218474/display-different-smiley-when-entering/218496#comment319921_218496) regarding *anonymous* functions and *globals* ;-) I understand your concerns regarding the missing {}, but (today) I prefer it this way - I  hope the readers can forgive me that ;-)   @JpaytonWPD

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but it *should* work:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(post_modified) AS modified FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if (isset($results[0]->modified) {
    header("Last-Modified: ".$results[0]->modified);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'theme_add_last_modified_header');

function theme_add_last_modified_header($headers) {
    global $post;
    if(isset($post) && isset($post->post_modified)){
        $post_mod_date=date("D, d M Y H:i:s",strtotime($post->post_modified));
        header('Last-Modified: '.$post_mod_date.' GMT');
     }
}
```

This worked for me on posts and pages :)